# Populate Collection cell afterwards Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, collections, cell

I have a mini game in Single-view-app project with item inventory (CollectionView). Its structure in main.Storyboard: CollectionView -> cell -> ContentView -> inventoryImageView. When the game starts `items.count` of empty cells are generated. Whenever a user taps on imageView of an item he finds,  I want this imageView to populate the most left and available cell of the inventory. Something like:

```
cell.inventoryImageView = itemImageView
```

How can I access this left unpopulated cell?

The code is:

```
struct Items {
    let imageName: String
    var location = (0, 0)
}
```

```
    var key = Items(imageName: "icons8-key-50")
    var chest = Items(imageName: "icons8-closed-treasure-chest-50")
    var rock = Items(imageName: "icons8-rock-50")
    var bone = Items(imageName: "icons8-human-bone-50")
    var mushroom = Items(imageName: "icons8-mushroom-50")
    
    var items = [Items]()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
        items = [key, chest, rock, bone, mushroom]
    }
```

when user clicks Start button this func gets triggered for every item :

```
func createItems(imageName: String) {
        let imageNamePNG = "\(imageName).png"
        let itemImage = UIImage(named: imageNamePNG)
        let itemImageView = UIImageView(image: itemImage) itemImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 0, width: 63, height: 63)
        itemImageView.frame = CGRect(x: Int.random(in: 70...294), y: Int.random(in: 100...543), width: 63, height: 63)
        view.addSubview(itemImageView)
        createdImages.append(itemImageView)
    }
```

cell creation part:

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.items.count
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            return cell
        }
```

[image: main.Storyboard:]

Comment: Could you publish your code? Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: Done. Is that enough?

Comment: Can you also publish a screenshot of the UIViewController with collection? I assume the collectionView is horizontal with 5 elements, right?

Comment: done. Only 4 elements can fit at the same time, but yeah, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to do but I hope this code could help you.

**CustomCollectionViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var inventoryImageView: UIImageView!
    
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageButton: UIButton!
    
    var key = Items(imageName: "img-1")
    var chest = Items(imageName: "img-2")
    var rock = Items(imageName: "img-3")
    var bone = Items(imageName: "img-4")
    var mushroom = Items(imageName: "img-5")
    
    var items = [Items]()
    var index = 0
    
    var createdImages = [Items]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.items = [key, chest, rock, bone, mushroom]
        
        self.imageButton.setImage(UIImage(named: self.items[index].imageName), for: .normal)
    }
    
    @IBAction func imageButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        index += 1
        if index >= items.count{
            index = 0
        }
    
        self.imageButton.setImage(UIImage(named: self.items[index].imageName), for: .normal)
        
        self.createdImages.append(self.items[index])
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.createdImages.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.inventoryImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.createdImages[indexPath.item].imageName)
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

**Items.swift**

```
struct Items {
    let imageName: String
    var location = (0, 0)
}
```

[image]